# Touch ID for single app

Tags: ios, touch-id

Is it possible to have Touch ID for just a single app? It seems to be just limited to the 5 fingerprints set in the settings.

Is there a way to have users enter fingerprints inside a created app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is possible to set UserFingerPrint for device TouchId. You can set only through device Setting app.